# Is it possible to blackbox vendor code when using VSCode's node debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Chrome Dev Tools has offered the ability to [blackbox](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing) selected code for a while now, but I can't seem to find a comparable feature for VSStudio when debugging Node.

I've been through the [debugger docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) and lots of issues on VSCode's Github, but I can't seem to find an answer.

**Is it possible to exclude (for example `node_modules/`) from debugging?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I haven't tried this I must admit, barely got round to use debugging in vscode just yet, but it does appear that blackbox-ing was supported in v1.8:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_node-debugging

> We have added a feature to avoid code that you don't want to step through. This feature can be enabled with the skipFiles setting in your launch configuration. skipFiles is an array of glob patterns for script paths to skip.

Files can be exluded using `skipFiles` in your launch configuration:

```
 "skipFiles": [
    "node_modules/**/*.js",
    "lib/**/*.js",
    "async_hooks.js",
    "inspector_async_hook.js"
  ]
```

Comment: Must be placed inside each configuration

Comment: Can Also use [`"<node_internals>/**"`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15464#issuecomment-332724821) to skip all the promise / event handling stuff

Comment: You can also blackbox a file during debugging  by running the command "Toggle Skipping File"

Comment: I had to use "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js". Skipping ${workspaceFolder} caused it to not work.