# How to disable "just my code" setting in VSCode debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When starting my project in the debugger (C# .NET Core), it states it's debugging "just my code".

I want to also debug the libraries, and can't see a setting to disable this anywhere in VSCode.

Is it possible to disable?

Comment: Do you have a skipFiles entry in your launch config?  That is how you would skip over vendor code for example.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620826/is-it-possible-to-blackbox-vendor-code-when-using-vscodes-node-debugger/48621036#48621036.  Perhaps you have a skipfiles entry you could delete or modify.  Does an extension set this or a similar value?

Comment: Related question: [How do I skip external code when debugging in VS Code](/q/47556495/11107541). I've written [an answer post](/a/77629203/11107541) there.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For this you need to change the `launch.json` file. Inside the `launch.json` file you have to set `"justMyCode"` to `false`.

As described [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#just-my-code). (I was pointed to that link through [this post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) on the Visual Studio Code site.)

Comment: That's for Visual Studio full, not Visual Studio code

Comment: @Revolt64 Sorry, I misread that. I edited my answer for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Edit: I had this in my launch.json file already, but due to it being at the bottom of the array and me accidentally adding a comma after the justMyCode line, it didn't work (that's what I get for a simple mistake). After removing the comma, it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: justMyCode is not a valid configuration for launch.json in vscode

Comment: In order to avoid redundant exceptions previous to the desired breakpoint, disable `Raised Exceptions` checkbox

Comment: How can I do this for tests, ie, debugging Pytest tests in VS Code?

Comment: Ok, I found it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests Same as for other Python modules, just with extra `"purpose": ["debug-test"],`

Answer (score 90):

Just adding `"justMyCode": false` to `launch.json` doesn't work. You need to add a separate config in `launch.json` like below. FYI each `{}` represents a config.

```
"configurations": [
        {
           .... # existing config
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
```

As pointed out in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7131#issuecomment-525873210)

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue. I put just my code "false" but I couldn't see frameworks libraries. So I changed the launch configuration as u said et voilà

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It's saying **Property is not allowed** for justMyCode (I'm using visual studio code 2018)

Comment: Hi there, I was using vscode 2019 during that time and It still works in vscode 2020.

Comment: This was actually the answer to my own question, but it should be noted that it is specific to *testing* in a *python* project, while it looks like the OP was interested in debugging a *launch* of a *C#* project. Also, an [outstanding bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14388) (at the time of writing) points out the ability to specify launch configs more globally (including the `justMyCode` option) via `settings.json`. (But the bug is that `justMyCode` is currently ignored in configurations for debugging unit tests.)

Comment: *This configuration can only be used by the test debugging commands. "request": "test" is deprecated use "purpose" instead.*

Comment: @cluis92, the editor says is not allowed, but it works in fact.

Comment: Note that you can also define launch configs in the global `settings.json` or your workspace settings (`foo.code-workspace`). In this case, you won't have a `launch.json`. Currently, VSCode isn't picking up these special "debug configs" if they are defined outside launch.json, because of this [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17644) (issue 17644). So, you need to create a `launch.json` for this solution to work. I did that by removing my launch configs from my workspace settings, and then moving them into `launch.json`.

Answer (score 42):

VSCode 1.60 was complaining about the `"request": "test"` method suggested by others.

But I did have to **add a new section** below my existing configuration to get `"justMyCode": false` to work.

Here is what worked for me:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "blah",
                "whatever"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug Unit Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

The **purpose** addition appears to be important.

I found the correct approach documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_debug-tests

Comment: You know, you saved my evening today. :) I hope you have a great weekend. ("purpose" was exactly the configuration I was looking for just now - thanks!)

Comment: A specially thanks for mentioned: "version": "0.2.0"!!!
Without that setting. I've fallen into that issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14381

Comment: Still not resolved with this solution too.

Comment: @y_159 Could you make a note for the plugin version, which runs the tests?
Cause I've struggled a lot with that sad issue)

Comment: Perhaps its could help: 
- be sure that you use standard ms-python.python extension
- don't forget check version flag in launch.json
- and.... the configuration with "name": "Python: Debug Unit Tests", should be last)

Comment: Ah, turns out it doesn't work if in **settings.json**, it has to be in **launch.json**, at least until https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18778 is fixed. (Doesn't help that the `Open 'launch.json'` command opens settings.json if you don't have a launch.json yet)

Comment: "purpose" fixed it, thanks! And this solution is by the way the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I added the "justMyCode": false" setting to launch.json and it still didn't stop at breakpoints in external library code. What was even more confusing: It did work for once and then suddenly it didn't anymore.

Then I found out: If you are in the "Run and Debug (SHIFT+CMD+D)"-tab and select your configuration there and click the green triangle / "Start Debugging (F5)" it works! However, if I click "Debug Python File" in the upper right corner it does not stop in external library code!

Comment: What in the actual heck. That worked. GRRRR

Answer (score 7):

If you're specifically debugging Python unit tests, adding `"justMyCode": "false"` to your normal config won't do, you'll need to add another in your launch.json with `"request": "test"`:

```
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "justMyCode": false,
        },
```

[Source: Github Microsoft/vscode-python Issue #7131](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7131#issuecomment-525873210)

Comment: This is kinda embarassing. I just realized my answer says almost the same as the one above. With my weary eyes when I posted, I couldn't make the difference between the my config and the one in that answer then wondered why it wouldn't work. So again I wanna emphasize the difference: `"request": "test"`

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022, VS Code no longer seems to have an “Open launch.json” shortcut in its command palette, but it still prompts you to edit launch.json to set "justMyCode" to false. The solution that worked for me was:

- create a directory called .vscode in the root of the repository
- create a file called launch.json in the .vscode directory
- put this text in the file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

There will be an error message under the word "test" saying that "test" is not a valid value, and that "attach" would be valid. However, it doesn't work for me if I change "test" to "attach". If the "version" field isn't there, it doesn't work and VS Code raises an error saying launch.json is missing a field.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me, it's plain and simple.
Basically,

1. just set "justMyCode": false
2. Then debug by pressing the **debugger button** at the **bottom panel**, instead of the top right corner.

Here's the main source.
https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/795#issuecomment-1310846015

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vscode on mac, press `shift+command+p`, search for `Open'launch.json'` (if you don't have the file, create it in the `.vscode` directory in the project), open an editor you want, and add the following JSON object to the file :

```
{
            "name": "Python: Debug Unit Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "purpose": ["debug-test"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
}
```

Reopen your vscode and now you can put breakpoints on lines that are imported or you have not written.

Answer (score 2):

In the documenentation of Visual Studio Code they have a section "[Skipping uninteresting code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome)".

> VS Code Node.js debugging has a feature to avoid source code that you don't want to step through (AKA 'Just My Code').
>   This feature can be enabled with the skipFiles attribute in your launch configuration. skipFiles is an array of glob patterns for script paths to skip.

In your launch.json file you have to add (or any other file you want to skip):

```
  "skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
    "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, even I faced this issue where the VS code was not taking the latest launch.json (one with 'justMycode: false'). So, I had to perform the following steps.

1. Instead of running a debugger from the Top right group menu of the editor, I ran it from below status bar as shown in the below picture

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvzUp.png) to see the screenshot of the status bar

2. Once clicked on this option a pop-up appears asking which launch.json you want to run your debugging with, as shown below.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCkFS.png) to see the screenshot of the pop-up menu

You can click on launch.json here to edit the configuration file and now the debugger opens with the selected launch.json and 'justtMycode:false' setting will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I added in the configurations part as below:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Curent File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand where the file needs to be and what exactly needs to be inside it. So here's what I've got for others to enjoy:

The `launch.json` file is not in the root of your project, it needs to be in `.vscode/launch.json` instead. And for new VSCode versions, once you open that file from that location, you can get warnings on issues in the file, and also automatically add sections to it.

For me, at the end the contents of the file is this:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        },
    ]
}
```

This allows me to enter (F11) other libs when I run a custom code in debug mode for Python.

Answer (score 0):

None of the fiddling with launch.json worked for me.
I had to tick the "Allow setting breakpoints in any files" box in the Settings:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I merged the previous answers and the below setting works for me (vscode 1.75.0).

```
"launch": {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "purpose": "debug-test",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "program": "${file}",
        }
    ],
},
```