# In python, VSCode debugger won't step into external code. Can't figure out how to edit "justMyCode" in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have been referring to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode
and
[How to disable "just my code" setting in VSCode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448/how-to-disable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger)

Despite many attempts, still unable to figure out where to put
"justMyCode": false in launch.json. Everywhere I try to put it the editor says "Property justMyCode is not allowed "

Below is a copy of my launch.json. Can someone tell me what should I do  ?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",

    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "."
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Unit Test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which debug configuration are you using (you list 7 of them)?

Answer (score 7):

It's not enough to `Try setting "justMyCode": false` as the message in the VS Code debugger suggests. You also need to change `"request": "launch"` to `"request": "test"` if you want to step through external code. Here's [the Github issue where I found this answer](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7347#issuecomment-530896261).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it just says `value is not accepted` after changing it to test

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, it says I must use "Python: Debug Unit Tests". But I'm not trying to debug a test. I'm trying a regular python file. Not sure what OP is trying to debug. Edit: I was able to get it to work by using "request:: "launch" and putting "justMyCode": false in my launch.json instead of the global vscode settings.

Comment: @cluis92 It shows that for me too, but I saved it anyway and ran the unit test with debugging and it worked fine.

Comment: This did the trick for me even though Vscode complained that `"test"` was not allowed (only "launch" or "attach" is allowed)

Comment: This is really confusing. It does not work for me. It marks the "value is not accepted" but following the suggestion above I ran it regardless but still does not work.

Answer (score 5):

you need to put `"purpose": ["debug-test"]` too.

like

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false,
        "purpose": ["debug-test"]
    }
],
```

Comment: this one is more updated