# VSCode not debugging into third side packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, ide

New to vscode and it seems fine, just that it doesn't seem to allow debugging into python packages I didn't write (not under the project folder?), neither does it allow me to add breakpoints to code that wasn't written by me.

I tried to set the "justMyCode": false configuration flag but it seems not to affect anything.

standard microsoft python and pylint extensions installed

Added according to request:

Version: 1.83.1 (Universal)
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:46:55.789Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.1.0

extensions:

Python
v2023.20.0
Microsoft
microsoft.com

Python Extension Pack
v1.7.0
Don Jayamanne

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, VSCode debugger won't step into external code. Can't figure out how to edit "justMyCode" in launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687113/in-python-vscode-debugger-wont-step-into-external-code-cant-figure-out-how-t)

Comment: Afraid not, I edit the launch.json just fine but it doesn't seem to recognize the relevant code, even if I open it manually and try to add breakpoints.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Include the version numbers for your Python extensions. 3) Give a [mre] that can be used to reproduce the problem including steps on where to put the breakpoint(s)

Comment: How do you use them? How to debug?  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: writing a minimal reproducible example would be too hard as I am trying to debug the merger of adapters for hugging face LLMs. I am quite certain however that this is a general vscode IDE problem and not something to do with the specific packages I'm trying to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a (very strange) way to run the debugger so that it works, apparently there is a difference between the debug code button that is part of the dropdown that also allows for a regular run and the run button that is next to the debug configuration button, the first doesn't seem to relate the IDE to the debug configuration json and thus disregards the "justmycode": false flag. Not sure why this is the case (I believe this is a general problem in vscode, perhaps
related to different python extensions).

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Comment: I can accept my own answer in 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the virtualenv, with `Shift + Ctrl + P` and write `Python: Select interpreter` and select the environment with the package installed. The problem could be that you ran the code with a different environment without the package installed.

Comment: No, the interpreter is pointing to the right virtual env, the package is running, just not recognized in any way by the debugger.

Comment: This happened to me, but in those cases was a script that executed other script. Could you explain better you case in order to help you? How is the output line in the terminal?

Comment: the 3rd party code is running, even working, I just want to debug it in order to better understand it, right now I'm debugging it with prints but I'm just not understanding why the justmycode flag doesn't seem to affect the vscode IDE.