# VSCode and Golang, How to Debug only my code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to enable "Just My Code" on VSCode when I'm debugging a Go app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a config in your `launch.json`?

```
"configurations": [
        {
           .... # existing config
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Go App",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "justMyCode": true,
        }
    ]
```

Refs:

- https://vscode-debug-specs.github.io/go/
- [How to disable "just my code" setting in VSCode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448/how-to-disable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger/52980481)

Comment: yes, I tried it, it doesn't work... and by the way, "True" is the default value