# How to ignore jQuery breakpoints when debugging in Visual Studio or Is it possible to blackbox js script in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The same question as [Is it possible to blackbox vendor code when using VSCode's node debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620826/is-it-possible-to-blackbox-vendor-code-when-using-vscodes-node-debugger)  but for Visual Studio 2019.

Every time I am debugging and I running into jquery.min.js it is taking long time to overcome it, I keep pressings Continue but it stepping there every time for a long time. How can I blackbox jquery.min.js in Visual Studio 2019?

[image: blackbox]

Comment: I am experiencing the same in VS 2022.  It does not always happen so it is hard to identify why.  I have to Continue up to 10 times sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place something like this in your launch configuration (launch.json):

```
"skipFiles": [
    "**/jquery*.min.js"
]
```